# No lines in buffer when writing in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm running MacVim with MiniBufExplorer amongst some other plugins. What I have noticed is that occasionally when I edit a file and try to write it (`:w`), I get the message

> --No lines in buffer--

If I then enter `:w` again the file writes successfully. It seems to sprout up randomly but once it starts happening it continues to happen with every file in the buffer until I close/restart MacVim.

**EDIT:**
Plugins currently used:

- Pathogen
- Ack
- Command-T
- MiniBufExpl
- Nerdtree
- Pep8
- Pydoc
- Ropevim
- Supertab
- Tagbar

Current .vimrc

```
filetype off
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

map <c-j> <c-w>j
map <c-k> <c-w>k
map <c-l> <c-w>l
map <c-h> <c-w>h

syntax on
filetype on
filetype plugin indent on

au FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"

set completeopt=menuone,longest,preview

map <leader>n :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

map <leader>j :RopeGotoDefinition<CR>
map <leader>r :RopeRename<CR>

map <leader>o :TagbarToggle<CR>

nmap <leader>a <Esc>:Ack!

autocmd BufEnter *.py set ai sw=4 ts=4 sta et fo=croql

colorscheme desert

map J 15j
map K 15k

set noswapfile
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
```

Comment: Is minibufexplorer relevant to your issue? Please add a list of plugins you use and also your vimrc.

Comment: @romainl I don't know for sure that it is relevant, but I figured since it is a buffer issue plugins that interact heavily with the buffer should be included. Also, when I googled around for this before it seems this message comes up in MBE threads a little bit. Added the full list and vimrc for reference, thanks

Comment: A few things about your `~/.vimrc`: 1) `filetype on` line is redundant. 2) your `<leader>j` and `<leader>r` mappings should probably be buffer mappings to only the python filetype. See `:h :map-local` 3) `J` is a rather useful command to simply override. See `:h J` Maybe you should use `<c-d>` instead? 4) `K` can also be rather useful. Your pydoc plugin also setups up a mapping to `K`. Maybe use `<c-u>` instead? See `:h K`

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks for the tips, I changed the `K` mapping in pydoc and found that I wasn't really using join that much. I should probably enable it in visual mode at least though. I found myself needing to scroll through files quite a bit and the `c-u` and `c-d` felt awkward to me.

Comment: @mattedgod I understand. I have mapped `<a-j>` and `<a-k>` to `<c-d>` and `<c-u>`.

Comment: @mattedgod Another suggestion: your "map" commands should probably be nnoremap commands. The leading n means only in normal mode (not visual/operator-pending mode) and the "nore" means not to follow any mappings in the right side of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was caused by minibufexplorer. The fix has been included in v6.5.0 of fholgado, consisting of inserting the `silent` keyword below in minibufexpl.vim

```
 " Delete all lines in buffer.
 silent 1,$d _
```